# What are these clips on the wires in my junction box?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Are these clips just for protection? or are they connectors for something?

[image]

Comment: what is that junction box for?  Connectors aren't weird.  The variety of wiring is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They look like a type of [push-in connector](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/tool-review-ideal-in-sure-push-in-wire-connectors/). If so they are in place of [twist-on wire connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist-on_wire_connector) and are not "just for protection", they are connecting the wires in a safe way.